# how to track the progress of a SQL update using progressbar in asp.net web page

Tags: asp.net, progress-bar, html

How to track the progress of a SQL update using progrss bar in asp.net web page?I need to run a query which will update a table in a database .the web page will show the progress while updating database when the start button is clicked.I tried the ajax controls but am not sure where the sql query should be placed.

Answer (score 1):

Every progress bar works in the same manner, no matter what you are performing behind the scenes.

Take a look at this very good article, explaining step by step, how you can implement the progress bar: [Using UpdateProgress Control Effectively](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNETAJAX/125_Using_UpdateProgress_Control_Effectively.aspx)